# Why does higher dimensional data has higher likelihood?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, sample-size, likelihood, variational-bayes, generative-models

I am reading about generative models. I came across an example a few times but I cannot come up with an explanation for it.

Imagine data is generated according to $p_\text{data}(x)$. It is often said that for higher dimensional data, the log-likelihood of the model also increases linearly with the dimension. Why is that the case ? I cannot wrap my head around this fact and any help would be very appreciated. I imagine $p_\text{data}(x)$ is a density and it might relate to the curse of dimensionality, but I still cannot show it semi-formally.

EDIT: I am not asking whether the likelihood increases with more samples, I am asking about two models with different input dimension, e.g. $x \in \mathbb R^{100}$ and $x \in \mathbb R^{500}$. Apparently, the likelihood of the true data generation process is higher when the dimension is larger, see deepgenerativemodels.github.io/assets/slides/cs236_lecture9.pdf, slide 5, and I do not understand why

Comment: Not sure which scaling exactly this refers to but, a likelihood $f(x;\theta)$ is still scales with the dimension of $x$

Comment: When you refer to "higher dimensional data", do you mean "larger sample size?"

Comment: Apologies for being unclear; I meant two different models with inputs of distinct dimension, eg 100 vs 100'000. Apparently having more dimensions make the likelihood higher, but I don't get why. My concern comes from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01844.pdf, section GREAT LOG-LIKELIHOOD AND POOR SAMPLES and https://deepgenerativemodels.github.io/assets/slides/cs236_lecture9.pdf, slide 5 with the same kind of example as the paper. I don't get the part "As we increase the dimension of x, absolute value of log p_{data}(x)
increases proportionally"

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. This is concerning the dimension of each sample, not the number of samples. An example: compare 50 samples from a multivariate Gaussian $(0, I)$ with 100 dimensions to 50 samples from a multivariate Gaussian $(0, I)$ with 10 dimensions. Numerically, the former will have larger log-likelihoods. (Larger, not higher—they're more negative.)

Comment: Please - in your edit - bear in mind that the likelihood does not become higher. It is a negative quantity whose absolute value grows. This is stated in the slides you cite as well.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384111/should-log-likelihood-values-increase-when-the-sample-size-of-a-simulation-incre

Comment: Can't the likelihood be positive ? E.g. for continous random variables ? @AryaMcCarthy

Comment: @Alf Likelihood can be positive, but what's important is the _direction_ of the growth!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this isn't always the case, it's just often the case when the data is sufficiently spread out *or* discrete.

Let's start with the discrete case because it's the easiest. Suppose in one dimension, you have $P(x_1)$. If you add a second dimension to this, you will now have $P(x_1 \cap x_2)$.

Note that $P(x_1 \cap x_2) = P(x_1) P(x_2 | x_1)$.

Because $P(x_2 | x_1) \le 1$, for all $x_2$, $P(x_1) \ge P(x_1 \cap x_2)$. So the maximum likelihood for the 2D distribution cannot be greater than the likelihood for a 1D distribution.

The concept is similar for continuous variables. However, the inequality does not always hold. In particular,

$f_{x_1 \cap x_2}(x_1, x_2) = f_{x_1}(x_1) f_{x_2|x_1}(x_2, x_1)$

So in this case, we will have $f_{x_1}(x_1) > f_{x_1 \cap x_2}(x_1, x_2)$ if and only if $f_{x_2|x_1}(x_2, x_1) < 1$. This isn't always true. As a very silly but illustrative example, suppose that somehow $f_{x_2|x_1}(x_2, x_1)$ was a Uniform(0, $\theta$) distribution. Then  the pdf is $1/\theta$, so if $\theta > 1$, then yes, $f_{x_1 \cap x_2}(x_1, x_2) < f_{x_1}(x_1)$. But if $\theta < 1$, then $f_{x_1 \cap x_2}(x_1, x_2) > f_{x_1}(x_1)$!

It's a little more complicated than this, but if the new dimensions are well spread out beyond a unit interval then the higher dimension likelihood is (probably) lower. But if it's well concentrated within a unit interval, this may not hold!

Comment: I think it exactly what I needed, thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Comment: Just wanted to drop a congrats for the great explanation